# In COM layer, how can we see singal data wrt PDU?

Tags: autosar

I am working on FlexRay communication on Autosar standard. The applications are setting signals to some defined values. But on FlexRay bus, these signals' values are somehow corrupted and I could see different values. To debug, I want to check PDUs and their signals' values in the COM layer. Is there anyway or buffer where I could see the PDUs and signals?

Comment: "Corrupted" in what way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Com buffer itself. That‘s where the signals are arranged into before sending or retrieved from on reception. For debugging, you‘ll need to have proper information about start positions, signal layout, length, type, and byte orientation on the respective Pdus.

For more information, please refer to the AUTOSAR SWS Com specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like CanOe and import a dbc containing your signal information.
Then, you can see every value of signal.
Or,
You could use an Ipdu callout in Com.
Set a breakpoint in the debugger to the callout.
When the Pdu is triggered to be sent, the breakpoint will be hit.
Then find the bit poisition/layout of your signal and find it in the Pdu buffer.